Is there any way I'd be able to study and work (Freelancer) in the UK?
Just like the title suggests, I want to study in the UK while being able to support myself.
I saw that it's not permitted to work on a student visa. Is there any other type of visa or a way that allows me to do both?

A youth mobiliy visa may be relevant.

The work conditions for students in the UK depends on the type of visa. Self-employment of any type is not allowed unless rule ST 26.8 is met.
The visas permitting study in the UK are:

Standard Visitor visa: study up to one month, no work allowed.
Short-term Student: study an English Language course of 11 months or less without a student sponsor but with an accredited provider. No work allowed
Student: work conditions apply, depending on the type of study


Student following a full-time course of degree level or above study:
20 hours per week during term-time (full- time employment permitted outside of term-time)


Student undertaking a full-time course below degree level: 10 hours per week during term-time (full- time employment permitted outside of term-time)


All other study, including all part-time study: No employment permitted

ST 26.5. A Student is not allowed to do any of the following:
(a) be self-employed or engage in business activity unless ST 26.8 applies; or
(b) work as a professional sportsperson (including as a sports coach); or
(c) work as an entertainer; or
(d) work in a position which would fill a permanent full-time vacancy unless ST 26.6. applies.
ST 26.8. A Student may be self-employed, if:
(a) they have applied for permission on the Start-up route; and
(b) that application is supported by an endorsement from a Start-up route endorsing body which is a higher education provider with a track record of compliance; and
(c) the application was made when the applicant had permission as a Student; and
(d) a decision has not been made on the application, or where the application has been refused, any Administrative Review against a refusal has not been finally determined.
